# How to define Map, where key is day and value is list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to define map where key is a day and value is List of posts. In the RequestMapping I give `/{year}/{month}/{day}` but day is optional. How to define map and return it to json to get json where days are from 1-31 and to days I've got  List of objects created in this day. My Controller code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/post/{year}/{month}/{day}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Post> getPostsByDate(@PathVariable("year") int year,
                                     @PathVariable("month") int month,
                                     @PathVariable("day") Optional<Integer> day)
   {


        if (day.isPresent()){
            return postRepository.findAllByCreateDate(year, month, day);
        } else return postRepository.findAllByMonthAndYear(year, month);

       List<Post> posts = postRepository.findAllByMonthAndYear(year, month);
       Map<Date, List<Post>> postMap =


   }
```

and post repository code:

```
   @Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
    List<Post> findAllByUser(User user);

    @Query("select p from Post p where (year(p.createDate) = ?1 and month(p.createDate) = ?2) order by p.createDate")
    List<Post> findAllByMonthAndYear(int year, int month);

    @Query("select p from Post p where (year(p.createDate) = ?1 and month(p.createDate) = ?2 and day(p.createDate) = ?3) order by p.createDate")
    List<Post> findAllByCreateDate(int year, int month, Optional<Integer> day);



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is like this, 
 Check if day (Key)  exists in map.

1) if Yes, Retrieve list of posts for that day and add new post to list

2) Else Add a new entry for date in map

```
if (day.isPresent()){
        return postRepository.findAllByCreateDate(year, month, day);
    } else return postRepository.findAllByMonthAndYear(year, month);

   List<Post> posts = postRepository.findAllByMonthAndYear(year, month);
   Map<Date, List<Post>> postMap = new HashMap();

 if(postMap.contains()){
    //Add record to list for day key
    postMap.put(day,postMap.get(day).add(postObject) ); 
  }else{
     //Add new entry for day
     List<Post> posts = new ArrayList();
     posts.add(postObject);
     postMap.put(day,postMap.get(day).add(posts) );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar can be achieved in more shorter form using java 8.

```
postMap.computeIfAbsent(day, k -> Collections.emptyList()).add(postObject);
```

And Another approach if POST class getDay method or some other method to get the day :

```
Map<Date, List<Post>> postMap = posts.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Post::getDay));
```

Both approach should work fine. Second one is more precise and declarative.